# Ошибка [32752] OleDB C# FireBird

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, firebird, oledb

использую LCPI.IBProvider.5 OLeDB,  делаю запрос базе данных и возвращает ошибку:

```
[LCPI.IBProvider.5] [Подсистема: isc_api.fb3_0] Внутренняя ошибка. Данные [индекс: 6] с неизвестным серверным sql-типом [32752].

Код ошибки COM: DB_E_NOTSUPPORTED.
```

Код метода:

```
   private List<BillServiceRaw> GetBillServices(FireBirdDBConnection connection, string filterHouseID, string filterIdent,
            DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            List<BillServiceRaw> result = new List<BillServiceRaw>();
            string identfilterquery = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterIdent) ? "" : " AND bill.LCS_LC_Key IN" +
                " (SELECT LC_Key FROM  Licco_adres WHERE LC_FKey IN ('" + filterIdent.Replace(",", "','") + "'))";
            string query = $@"
SELECT 
     (SELECT LC_FKey FROM Licco_adres WHERE LC_Key = bill.LCS_LC_Key) Ident
   , LCS_LC_Key  UniqueNum
   , CAST(bill.LCS_MonY as Date) Datee
   , usl.UU_Name Service
   , bill.LCS_UU_Key ServiceID
   , (case 
        WHEN bill.LCS_UU_Key IN (724) THEN 0
        when bill.LCS_Type IN (8)    THEN -bill.LCS_Sum 
     else 0 
     end) Debt  
   , (bill.LCS_Sum1) VolumeInd
   , (bill.LCS_Sum2) Rate
   , (case 
        when bill.LCS_Type IN (5)    THEN  LCS_Sum 
     else 0 
     end) MoneyRecalculation
   , (case 
        when bill.LCS_Type IN (1,17)    THEN  LCS_Sum  
        WHEN bill.LCS_Type IN (2,3,4,9,18)  THEN -LCS_Sum 
        WHEN LCS_Type IN (7) AND LCS_MonYTo > LCS_MonY THEN LCS_Sum 
     else 0 
     end) AccountingPeriodTotal
   , (case 
        when bill.LCS_Type IN (1,5,17)    THEN  LCS_Sum  
        WHEN bill.LCS_Type IN (2,3,4,9,18)  THEN -LCS_Sum 
        WHEN LCS_Type IN (7) AND LCS_MonYTo > LCS_MonY THEN LCS_Sum 
     else 0 
     end) TotalPayable
     
FROM Licco_sum_now bill
     LEFT JOIN spr_usl usl ON usl.UU_Key = bill.LCS_UU_Key
    
WHERE
    bill.LCS_MonY BETWEEN '{start}' AND '{end}'
    { identfilterquery } ";
          

            OleDbCommand command = createCMD(connection, query);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                    BillServiceRaw item = new BillServiceRaw()
                    {
                        Ident = reader[0].ToString(),
                        UniqueNum = reader[1].ToString(),
                        Date = DateTime.Parse(reader[2].ToString()),
                        Service=reader[3].ToString(),
                        ServiceId=int.Parse(reader[4].ToString()),
                        Debt=decimal.Parse(reader[5].ToString()),
                        VolumeInd= decimal.Parse(reader[6].ToString()),
                        Rate= decimal.Parse(reader[7].ToString()),
                        MoneyRecalculation= decimal.Parse(reader[8].ToString()),
                        AccountingPeriodTotal= decimal.Parse(reader[9].ToString()),
                        TotalPayable= decimal.Parse(reader[10].ToString())
                    };
                        result.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            command.Transaction.Commit();
            return result;
        }
```

в базе данных 7-ой столбик имеет тип decimal(19,6)
Хотелось бы отметить что в запрос корректен и выполняется в среде.
Заранее спасибо всем!

Comment: Не используйте конкатенацию/интерполяцию строк для составления SQL-запроса! Используйте параметризованный запрос.

Comment: `SomeType.Parse(reader[x].ToString())` - что это? Есть же методы наподобие [GetDecimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getdecimal?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: `reader[6].GetType()` - что выдаст?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, здравствуйте, на счет использования  конкатенаций и интерполяций я знаю, что нужно параметры использовать, код не мой, мне достался он вместе с проектом, на счет getdecimal, спасибо не знал. getType не работает, прям на этой строке кидает исключение такое же